# How can I solve this problem, and what kind of algorithm is the appropriate on if any to solve it

Tags: java, algorithm

There is an array which contains non negative integers. I need to find a subarray (if there's one) that contains numbers that have a sum which equals to a given number (target). I wrote this code that works but I try to write it in a more efficient way (O(n)).

```
public static void solvedNotSoEnhanced(int[] arr, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length-1;i++) {
        int cur_sum = 0;
        for (int j = i ; j <= arr.length-1; j++) {
            cur_sum += arr[j];
            if (cur_sum > target) {
                break;
            } else if (cur_sum == target) {
                System.out.println("start: " + i + " end: " + j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to find all subarrays or is just one enough?

Comment: I need to find all the subarras.

Comment: If all the elements of the array are positive. If a subarray has sum greater than the given sum then there is no possibility that adding elements to the current subarray the sum will be x (given sum). Idea is to use a similar approach to a sliding window. Start with an empty subarray, add elements to the subarray until the sum is less than x. If the sum is greater than x, remove elements from the start of the current subarray. But I do not understand how to implemnt it properly

Comment: Use just one loop (not two nested ones) and in each iteration modify the start or the end index of the subarray.

Comment: In this code I am traversing the array and when I find all the subarrays I print them. However, it is not taking out the numbers from the start when the given sum becomes bigger than the sum of integers in array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick lies in the restriction:

> There is an array which contains non negative integers.

This means that when you're going through your input front-to-back, you presume that the 'start' of the subarray is at index 0, and then you start adding each number in sequence. There are only 3 options, *because* of that restriction:

1. Adding the new number results in a sum that is less than the desired number. In which case, keep going.
2. Adding the new number results in an exact match to the desired number. You've found the subsequence and the algorithm is done.
3. Adding the new number results in a sum that is more. In which case, the only answer can lie in moving the *start* up: Element 0 is *not* part of the solution.

Thus:

```
static void solvedNotSoEnhanced(int[] arr, int target) {
    if (target < 1) {
        // Always mind your corner cases!
        System.out.println("(0, 0)");
        return;
    }

    int start = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];

        while (sum > target) {
            // Target exceeded; move up our startpoint.
            sum -= arr[start];
            start++;
        }

        // If we get here, we found our subsequence!
        if (sum == target) {
            System.out.println("[" + start + ", " + i + "]");
            return;
        }
    }
    return "No subsequence";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I have used sliding window approach. Mainly I am storing the sum of elements of array as I traverse them. Then I just store 2 pointers i and j which store the position of current sub array under consideration.

```
public static void solvedNotSoEnhanced(int[] arr, int target) 
{
  for(int i = 1;i>arr.length;i++)
  {
    arr[i] += arr[i-1];
  }
  
  int i=0,j=1;
  while(i<arr.length &&j<arr.Length)
  {
    int sum = arr[j] - arr[i];
    if(sum == target) System.out.println("start: " + (i + 1) + " end: " + j);
    else if(sum > target) i++;
    else j++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in `O(nlogn + m)`, where `n` is the array size, and `m` is the number of subarrays matching the restriction.

First, create an auxillary array `sum`, which is the summation of all elements up to the current:

```
sum[i] = arr[0] + arr[1] + ... + arr[i]
Or (equivalent definition)
sum[0] = arr[0]
sum[i] = sum[i-1] + arr[i]
```

Now, note that `sum` is sorted (increasing) array (since all elements are not negative).

So, after the array is generated, you can iterate `sum`, and for each `i` in `sum`, look for `k-sum[i]` using binary search, which will give you index `j` if the element exists, and (i,j) is such a subarray.

Using a hash table to store the sums instead can also be done to further reduce complexity to `O(n)` on average case.

Comment: Actually O(n) can be easily achieved without auxiliary data structures using the sliding window approach outlined by the OP.